# Why use z_mean to plot the latent space learned by a Variational Autoencoder?

Tags: keras, variational-autoencoder

In the Keras website, there is an [example code](https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/) of a Variational Autoencoder.

At the end of such a page, there is an example code that plots the latent space learned from MNIST. The code is as follows:

```
def plot_label_clusters(vae, data, labels):
    # display a 2D plot of the digit classes in the latent space
    z_mean, _, _ = vae.encoder.predict(data)
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))
    plt.scatter(z_mean[:, 0], z_mean[:, 1], c=labels)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.xlabel("z[0]")
    plt.ylabel("z[1]")
    plt.show()
```

Pay attention to the very first line of code of the function `plot_label_clusters()`. The data is predicted from the encoder part. The encoder ends with the outputs of three layers, in this order: `z_mean`, `z_log_var` and `z`.

My understanding is that `z` is the latent space and `z_mean` is just the learned means from the sampled data. If this is correct, why the latent space is plotted from `z_mean` and not from `z`?